# 502 bad gateway with nginx and gunicorn

Tags: python, django, nginx, gunicorn

```
502 Bad Gateway
nginx/1.19.5
```

reinstall portainer and recreate docker images to solve this isssue, but didnt work.
how can i solve this issue?

i think something's wrong before collectstatic
because if this issue was about collectstatic, webpage have been deployed with static files not applied.

gunicorn container logs

```
0 static files copied to '/home/loldb/staticfiles', 147 unmodified.
Operations to perform:
  Apply all migrations: accountapp, admin, articleapp, auth, commentapp, contenttypes, profileapp, projectapp, sessions, subscribeapp
Running migrations:
  No migrations to apply.
0 static files copied to '/home/loldb/staticfiles', 147 unmodified.
Operations to perform:
  Apply all migrations: accountapp, admin, articleapp, auth, commentapp, contenttypes, profileapp, projectapp, sessions, subscribeapp
Running migrations:
  No migrations to apply.
0 static files copied to '/home/loldb/staticfiles', 147 unmodified.
Operations to perform:
  Apply all migrations: accountapp, admin, articleapp, auth, commentapp, contenttypes, profileapp, projectapp, sessions, subscribeapp
Running migrations:
  No migrations to apply.
0 static files copied to '/home/loldb/staticfiles', 147 unmodified.
Operations to perform:
  Apply all migrations: accountapp, admin, articleapp, auth, commentapp, contenttypes, profileapp, projectapp, sessions, subscribeapp
Running migrations:
  No migrations to apply.
```

nginx logs

```
/docker-entrypoint.sh: /docker-entrypoint.d/ is not empty, will attempt to perform configuration
/docker-entrypoint.sh: Looking for shell scripts in /docker-entrypoint.d/
/docker-entrypoint.sh: Launching /docker-entrypoint.d/10-listen-on-ipv6-by-default.sh
10-listen-on-ipv6-by-default.sh: Getting the checksum of /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
10-listen-on-ipv6-by-default.sh: Enabled listen on IPv6 in /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
/docker-entrypoint.sh: Launching /docker-entrypoint.d/20-envsubst-on-templates.sh
/docker-entrypoint.sh: Configuration complete; ready for start up
2024/01/08 02:17:16 [emerg] 1#1: host not found in upstream "django_container_gunicorn" in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:22
nginx: [emerg] host not found in upstream "django_container_gunicorn" in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:22
/docker-entrypoint.sh: /docker-entrypoint.d/ is not empty, will attempt to perform configuration
/docker-entrypoint.sh: Looking for shell scripts in /docker-entrypoint.d/
/docker-entrypoint.sh: Launching /docker-entrypoint.d/10-listen-on-ipv6-by-default.sh
10-listen-on-ipv6-by-default.sh: Getting the checksum of /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
10-listen-on-ipv6-by-default.sh: Enabled listen on IPv6 in /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
/docker-entrypoint.sh: Launching /docker-entrypoint.d/20-envsubst-on-templates.sh
/docker-entrypoint.sh: Configuration complete; ready for start up
2024/01/08 02:17:34 [error] 29#29: *1 connect() failed (113: No route to host) while connecting to upstream, client: 10.0.0.2, server: , request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://10.0.17.2:8000/", host: "--.--.--.--"
10.0.0.2 - - [08/Jan/2024:02:17:34 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 502 157 "-" "ELB-HealthChecker/2.0"
2024/01/08 02:17:36 [error] 29#29: *3 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 10.0.0.2, server: , request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://10.0.17.2:8000/", host: "--.--.--.--"
10.0.0.2 - - [08/Jan/2024:02:17:36 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 502 157 "-" "ELB-HealthChecker/2.0"
10.0.0.2 - - [08/Jan/2024:02:17:44 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 499 0 "-" "ELB-HealthChecker/2.0"
2024/01/08 02:17:51 [error] 29#29: *7 connect() failed (113: No route to host) while connecting to upstream, client: 10.0.0.2, server: , request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://10.0.17.2:8000/", host: "--.--.--.--"
10.0.0.2 - - [08/Jan/2024:02:17:51 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 502 157 "-" "ELB-HealthChecker/2.0"
2024/01/08 02:18:04 [error] 29#29: *9 connect() failed (113: No route to host) while connecting to upstream, client: 10.0.0.2, server: , request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://10.0.17.2:8000/", host: "--.--.--.--"
10.0.0.2 - - [08/Jan/2024:02:18:04 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 502 157 "-" "ELB-HealthChecker/2.0"
2024/01/08 02:18:08 [error] 29#29: *11 connect() failed (113: No route to host) while connecting to upstream, client: 10.0.0.2, server: , request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://10.0.17.2:8000/", host: "--.--.--.--"
10.0.0.2 - - [08/Jan/2024:02:18:08 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 502 157 "-" "ELB-HealthChecker/2.0"
10.0.0.2 - - [08/Jan/2024:02:18:14 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 499 0 "-" "ELB-HealthChecker/2.0"
2024/01/08 02:18:18 [error] 29#29: *15 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 10.0.0.2, server: , request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://10.0.17.2:8000/", host: "--.--.--.--"
10.0.0.2 - - [08/Jan/2024:02:18:18 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 502 157 "-" "ELB-HealthChecker/2.0"
```

Django Settings

```
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent.parent
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')

STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    BASE_DIR / "static",
    ]
```

Dockerfile

```
FROM python:3.9.0

WORKDIR /home/loldb/

RUN mkdir /root/.ssh/ && \
    chmod 700 /root/.ssh/ && \
    touch /root/.ssh/known_hosts && \
    ssh-keyscan github.com >> /root/.ssh/known_hosts

ADD ./.ssh/id_rsa /root/.ssh/id_rsa
RUN chmod 600 /root/.ssh/id_rsa

RUN git clone git@github.com:----/----.git .

RUN echo "delete caches!"

COPY requirements.txt /home/loldb/requirements.txt
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

RUN pip install gunicorn
RUN pip install mysqlclient

EXPOSE 8000

CMD ["bash", "-c", "python manage.py collectstatic --noinput --settings=loldb.settings.deploy && \
    python manage.py migrate --settings=loldb.settings.deploy"]
```

nginx.conf

```
worker_processes auto;

events{

}

http {
  server {
    listen 80;

    include mime.types;

    location /static/ {
      alias /data/static/;
    }

    location /media/ {
      alias /data/media/;
    }

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://django_container_gunicorn:8000;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        
        proxy_connect_timeout 300s;
        proxy_read_timeout 600s;
        proxy_send_timeout 600s;
        proxy_buffers 8 16k;
        proxy_buffer_size 32k;
    }
  }
}
```